# fetching integers using valueForKey using swift

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsarray, nsurlsession

I have developed an easy app that fetches json data and puts the values inside a TableView. Everything works fine when I use valueForKey and I fetch a String Value.

But when I try to fetch an Integer like an id....I get this error after the app launches successfully.

OUTPUT shows nil

**GREEN ERROR**

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x110c05980:  pushq  %rbp
0x110c05981:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x110c05984:  pushq  %rbx
0x110c05985:  pushq  %rax
0x110c05986:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x110c05989:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x110c0598c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x110c0598e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x110c05991:  je     0x110c059ac               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 44
0x110c05993:  movq   0x7f236(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x110c0599a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x110c0599d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x110c059a0:  callq  0x110c0846a               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x110c059a5:  testb  %al, %al
0x110c059a7:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x110c059aa:  je     0x110c059b3               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x110c059ac:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x110c059b0:  popq   %rbx
0x110c059b1:  popq   %rbp
0x110c059b2:  retq   
0x110c059b3:  leaq   0xc158(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x110c059ba:  movq   %rax, 0x87427(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x110c059c1:  int3   
0x110c059c2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

**Is there anyway that I could fetch an id with valueForKey or another method? Or is there a way to convert it into a String given that valueForKey may only accept Strings?**

New to iOS please help.

**JSON DATA**

```
println(self.jsonData)

(
        {
        id = 1;
        name = "Tommy";
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = "Dad";
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        name = "Mom";
    },
        {
        id = 4;
        name = "Vic";
    },
        {
        id = 5;
        name = "Tom";
    },
        {
        id = 6;
        name = "Pam";
    }
)
```

**VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
var jsonData = NSArray()
var mydata = NSArray()

func fetchData() {

    var url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/fetch.json")

    var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {
        (data, response, error) in

        var error: NSError?

       ### parse data into json
        self.jsonData =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray!

       ### grab the data for populating the tableview
       ### ID is an integer value, so how can i fetch it if I can't use valueForKey?
        self.mydata = self.jsonData.valueForKey("id") as NSArray!

        ###This works fine
        //self.mydata = self.jsonData.valueForKey("name") as NSArray!

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // reload the tableview
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Edit your question to include the actual error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
var mydata = NSArray()
```

to:

```
var mydata:[Int] = []
```

and replace:

```
self.mydata = self.jsonData.valueForKey("id") as NSArray!
```

with:

```
for dict in self.jsonData as [NSDictionary] {
    if let idnum = dict["id"] as? Int {
        println("id is an Int")
        self.mydata.append(idnum)
    } else if let idnum = dict["id"] as? String {
        println("id is actually a string")
        self.mydata.append(idnum.toInt() ?? 0)
    }
}
```

According the the OP, this printed "id is an Int" multiple times, so now we know that id is an `Int` we can clean it up:

```
// Loop over the array of dictionaries
for dict in self.jsonData as [NSDictionary] {
    // For this entry, get the id number from the dictionary
    // and append it to the mydata array
    if let idnum = dict["id"] as? Int {
        self.mydata.append(idnum)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, can you clarify where I should add this to my code...:/

Comment: Also i get, Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Comment: i receive the error, NSNumber is not a subtype of NSArray

Comment: Do you want self.mydata to be the array of id values: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: error: NSArray does not have a member name 'append'

Comment: it prints id is an Int. multiple times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62855/discussion-between-vacawama-and-surge-pedroza).